# semantic UI dropdown not working with ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dropdown, semantic-ui

Please see the plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YeOJjf6AZyJ7hAfpFfsK?p=preview

In the Plunker, you could see that the *color* dropdown is working fine but the *shape* dropdown is not. I am guessing this is because I use `ng-repeat` for the *shape*.

The *color* html is

```
<select class="ui dropdown">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

while the *shape* html is

```
<select class="ui dropdown">
  <option ng-repeat="test in tests" value="{{test}}">{{test}}</option>
</select>
```

I cannot find any mistake in the code. How to make dropdown work with the `ng-repeat`?

Please go the above Plunker link for more details. Thanks.

## ------- **UPDATE**

I've got it worked by moving

```
$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
```

from *app.js* controller to *index.html* `<script></script>`. See Plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/NIZ20VKFYb2QfKyr91Lz?p=preview.

But still, I don't understand why `$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();` within controller doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the way Semantic renders stuff. I found this workaround on another post

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="Role">Role</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
      <div class="default text">{{test}}</div>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="menu">
            <div ng-repeat="test in tests" class="item" ng-click="setTest(test)">{{test}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/X1qxtVM15xNFvdzlkeYE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I still want to understand why `ng-repeat` in `<option>` not working.